# jquery ajax form not working when the document changed

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post

i have the signup form and one terms link

when i click on the terms link will send ajax post request to server

then server return the terms and append to the web page,the form element will remove

if i click a button will send another ajax post request to server

server return the signup form html and append to the web page

issue is,when the web page recieve the signup form and type some to signup

default(first time enter the page) when the form submit will use ajax to send request

and do function if success,but if i clicked terms and click back to signup form

then fill up and submit the form,the ajax not works,the form uses GET request and url also changed

i can't find anything in the debug console

ps.don't tell me avoid remove form element

Comment: If I understood that correctly you have the same form once filled by the user, the other time filled through your js code. To preserve the event handlers (e.g. the ajax request instead of default form behavior) attached to the form you could use jQuery's [.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) instead of removing it.

Comment: i use empty() function,how can i change to detach()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you're setting the `submit` event before the form is loaded. If so, the event won't be attached to it. You should use `.on()` (http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Your `submit` event should look like this:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#formSelector', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // your Ajax code
});
```

Comment: not work.after click the submit url didn't append GET query string,but refresh to root(/) instead sending ajax request